# Why can I not instantiate a class whose constructor is private in a friend class?

Tags: c++, constructor, friend-class

I have two classes; `Salary` that is intended to hold information and calculations regarding the salary of an employee and `Employee` that has an object of type `class Salary` and some members like name and address of the employee...

- What I want to do is to prevent `class Salary` from being instantiated except by  `class Employee`. So I declared the constructors of `Salary` private and made `Employee` a friend of `Salary`. But I get errors:

  ```
  class Employee;

  class Salary {
      public:

      private:
          Salary() : revenue_{}, cost_{} {}
          Salary(int x, int y) : revenue_{ x },
          cost_{ y } {

          }
          int revenue_, cost_;
          friend class Employee;
  };

  class Employee {
      public:
          std::string name_;
          Salary sal;
  };

  int main(){

      Employee emp{}; // "Salary::Salary()" is inaccessible
  }
  ```
- The problem goes away if I forward declare `main`:

  ```
  int main(int, char*[]);
  ```

  And make `main` a friend of `class Salary` like so in Salary:

  ```
  class Salary {
      //...
      friend int main(int argc, char* argv[]);
  };
  ```

Now the program compiles correctly!

*** Another thing in main if I declare an object this way:

```
Employee emp; // ok
Employee emp{}; // error?
```

Comment: Why are you making `Salary`'s constructor private? It seems like there are contexts when you'd want to use `Salary` outside of `Employee`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because you don't provide a constructor for `Employee` the braces in your initialization `Employee emp{};` will perform an [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), which essentially means that each member is initialized one-by-one using the default rules, in the context of `main()`. Since `main()` doesn't have access to the `Salary` constructor, it fails.

As others have pointed out, adding an `Employee` default constructor will resolve your problem:

```
class Employee {
    public:
        Employee() = default;
        std::string name_;
        Salary sal;
};
```

Comment: I'm trying on MSVS and only `Employee() {};` allows `Employee emp{};` to compile. Clang seems to accept `Employee() =  default;`, but then again, Clang [seems to accept](https://godbolt.org/z/Tebcbg) having no default constructor here.

Comment: GCC [does the same as Clang](https://godbolt.org/z/-1LHP8), and doesn't need a default constructor to compile in this case. Have you tried this answer on any specific compiler?

Comment: Thanks. it saves the day!

Answer (score 4):

You need `Employee`'s ctor to call the ctor of `Salary`.  The ctor of `Salary` is not accessible from `main`.

eg:

```
class Employee {
public:
    Employee() : sal() {}
    public:
        std::string name_;
        Salary sal;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you erase the "{}" after "Employee emp" in your main() function it compiles just fine (gcc 7.3.1 on Fedora 27).

Comment: I recommend explaining why.

Comment: Yes. Not onyl GCC but also MSVC14 also compiles `Employee emp;` but why?

Comment: @Syfu_H [Value Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization). And I could be mistaken here (been caught on this in the past), but the Value Initialization is being replaced by [Aggregate Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization)

Answer (score 1):

You have to explicitly declare the default constructor of class `Employee` thus you can initialize an abject via `uniform initialization`:

```
class Employee {
    public:
        Employee(){} // add it
        std::string name_;
        Salary sal;
};

int main(){
    Employee emp{}; // now this should compile

}
```